# Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier ... could not be found

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have been fighting this issue for days now and about to beat my head against the wall and put myself out of my code signing/app submission misery.

I have an application that has been submitted to the app store and accepted no problems (ver 1.0.0).  I was able to publish the first update (ver 1.0.1) with a little bit of trial an error using XCode 3.2.4 and iOS 4.1 via Application Loader.  Now I am on XCode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 and am trying to publish an update (ver 1.0.2) via XCode Organizer.

I can successfully build my application against the AppStore Distribution provision when I set my Bundle Identifier in the info.plist to "com.myCompany.myApp".  But when I try to Validate/Submit the build via Organizer I get and error stating "Bundle Identifier: com.myCompany.myApp differs from prior bundle identifier ABC123XYZ1.com.myCompany.myApp".  Apparently when I first submitted my app via iTunes connect I used the full (*AppId*).*BundleIdentifer* syntax.  I have verified this by viewing the Bundle ID in iTunes connect.

So, logically, I added in the AppId prefix to the bundle identifier in the Info.plist file.  When I do this and try to build again, I get "Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier ... could not be found." and the build fails.

I have tried everything I have read everything on the internet regarding these two errors with no resolution to the problem.  I am in a catch 22 situation.  I can't build the app with the AppID prefix in the bundle identifer and I can't submit it to iTunesConnect without it.  Also, the iTunesConnect error occurs when trying to use Application Loader to upload the app.

I am prepared to offer my first born to anyone who can help me get out of this code signing/app submission hell!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after waiting 2 months for an answer from the iTunes team, which never came, I have figured out a way around this issue and got my app to upload.  The key is to make the bundle identifier match the bundle id that is registered in iTunesConnect.  In this case the bundle id in iTunesConnect was in the form of 1234567890.com.companyname.appname.  Some how when I first created my app I had included the bundle seed id which from my research should not have been included when the app was created in iTunesConnect.

To resolve the issue, I created a new App ID in the provisioning portal in the form of 1234567890.1234567890.com.companyname.appname and then created a new distribution mobile provision based on this new AppID.  I downloaded and installed the mobile provision in xCode Organizer.  In the info.plist of my xCode project I set the bundle identifier to 1234567890.com.companyname.appname.  This allowed xCode to match the mobile provision to the specified bundle identifier in the info.plist and successfully build and sign my app with a bundle identifier that matched the bundle id in iTunesConnect.  In organizer I was able to validate and upload the app successfully.

Comment: This saved me in Unity. I was including the bundle ID in the string - removing it made the provision get recognized.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to first BUILD the app with Cmd-B.

This popped up a keychain window access asking me to "Allow" (or "Always Allow") Xcode to access the keychain.

Only THEN could I actually run the program to launch it on my iPhone.

Apparently, hitting only run didn't do the trick.

(Btw, remember to first sign your app with the "iPhone Developer: Your Name ()" key.

Answer (score 0):

Even it sounds odd that your bundle identifier has changed, there is one thing that comes to my mind that you could try.

Create a new provisioning profile, which's identifier matches the one you used to submit your first version of your app.

Comment: I created a new AppStore Distribution provisioning profile and tied it to the same App ID that the original one was created against.  I got the same issue.  XCode does not recognized the provisioning profile when the Bundle Identifer in the info.plist includes the App ID prefix.  I can't create a new App ID with the same bundle indentifer as this is not allowed.  I don't want to create a new App ID with a different bundle identifier as I believe this will disconnect the app from its previous releases.

Comment: so, for whatever strange reason your bundle-id in itunes connect contains the app-Id, which it shouldn't. If that is so I would contact the support, since you don't enter your bundle-id manually in itunes connect, but select an already present app-id. (maybe this has been different before I first submitted an app)

Comment: That is correct.  The Bundle ID in iTunesConnect is "AppID.com.myCompany.myApp".  I guess when I first submitted my app back in the days of iOS 3.1.3 iTunesConnect allowed me to include the AppID.  So my only recourse is to contact Apple and see if they can change it (which I doubt) or is it possible to enter "AppID.com.myCompany.myApp" in the Bundle Identifier field in the info.plist and get xCode recognize that I have a valid mobile provision?

Comment: Mike, did you contact apple? any progress so far?

Comment: I have not heard back from Apple yet.  I submitted two requests via the iTunesConnect contact us page but got no response.  I currently have an iOS Developer Support request in and am awaiting a response to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and with the advice of codeySmurf above I was able to reuse the same id and it removed that error.