# Testing app in my device

Tags: xcode

When I testing my app in my device in X-code I get this message:

Check dependencies

Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'mycompany.myappname' could not be found

So, What is the problem?

Comment: Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471389/code-sign-error-a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the SOLUTION. I didn't write good the bundle identifier. So guys this is very important, your app's bundle identifier must be identical to the app id's bundle identifier in the developer portal! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a provisioning profile in the developer portal and then set this up in xcode / your app before you can run it.

Comment: I have provisioning profile in the developer portal...

Comment: When I refresh my organizer I get this: No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.